# How do I create a filter to select a single term from a string in Tableau? I need to be able to select multiple terms

Tags: excel, string, visualization, tableau-api, data-analysis

for example my data looks something like this:

| Name | Age | Dessert |
| --- | --- | --- |
| maria | 12 | cake; ice cream; cookies; candy |
| hannah | 20 | cake; candy |
| brian | 8 | ice cream; cookies |
| liam | 13 | candy |
| julie | 32 | cake; cookies |

I want to create a filter like this that allows MULTI-SELECT:

```
Dessert
[]cake
[]ice cream
[]cookies
[]candy
```

A parameter did not work for me since it doesn't allow multi-select.
Please help!! Thanks so much!

edit: not sure if it matters but i have the data set up in an excel sheet if an edit there could help! but i need all the terms in a single filter! thanks!

Comment: I think your best bet is to use the data tools in Tableau to transform your data. If you don't have access to Tableau Prep, you may want to handle transforming your data using Excel functions.

Comment: There are multiple links on the web about this topic, this is [one](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/) of them

Comment: i need the multi selection in tableau not excel ^

Answer (score 0):

i found that the best way to do this was to pivot the columns into rows in either tableau prep or using python. thank you for your help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).